# Exception with elasticSearch and AWS plugin

Tags: amazon-ec2, elasticsearch, sbt-aws-plugin

I'm trying to deploy elasticSearch on my EC2 instance, but I got this error  :

```
    [2014-04-04 12:23:30,499][INFO ][node                     ] [Franklin Hall] version[1.0.1], pid[4516], build[5c03844/2014-02-25T15:52:53Z]
    [2014-04-04 12:23:30,500][INFO ][node                     ] [Franklin Hall] initializing ...
    [2014-04-04 12:23:30,531][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Franklin Hall] loaded [cloud-aws], sites []
    {1.0.1}: Initialization Failed ...
    - ExecutionError[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException]
    NoClassDefFoundError[org/elasticsearch/ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException]
    ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException]
```

when I launch ElasticSearch with the command

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch -Xss256k -Xmx2048m
```

Here is my installed versions :

```
Elastic Search 1.0.1
Elasticsearch-cloud-aws 1.0.0
```

Do you guys have any idea of what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what `-Xss256k -Xmx2048m` parameters are but [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/elasticsearch-on-ec2/) and [this one](http://chrissimpson.co.uk/using-elasticsearch-on-amazon-ec2.html) tutorials worked perfect for me.

Both suggest `sudo bin/elasticsearch -f` so try this one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your links help me to understand what was going wrong :) btw be aware that the -f option is deprecated in the last versions of elasticsearch [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/_system_and_settings.html)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. With me it was, that I installed from Ubuntu repositories and followed the tutorials that suggested installation of elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/1.4.0.

If you have done that than

`cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
sudo bin/plugin -remove elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/1.4.0`

and to install the working version, do

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
sudo bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/2.2.0
```

Comment: THanks for the tip: fixed it for me as well!